# how to make concentric circles layout in igraph (R)

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to create a special graph layout where 2 different types of nodes (based on their attribute) are placed on 2 different circles with different radius (concentric circles layout).

Here's a toy example where a graph with 10 nodes have an attribute (size). The goal is to place the nodes with size less than 5 on an inner circle, and the nodes with size greater than 5 on an outer circle:

```
g <- make_full_graph(10)
V(g)$size = V(g)
```

I couldn't find any such layout supported by igraph library. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `layout_in_circle` option if you only wanted one circle. You could apply that separately to each of your groups with something like this

```
layout_in_circles <- function(g, group=1) {
    layout <- lapply(split(V(g), group), function(x) {
        layout_in_circle(induced_subgraph(g,x))
    })
    layout <- Map(`*`, layout, seq_along(layout))
    x <- matrix(0, nrow=vcount(g), ncol=2)
    split(x, group) <- layout
    x
}
```

Then you could plot with

```
plot(g, layout=layout_in_circles(g, group=V(g)>5))
```

It doesn't do anything special to try to make the edges pretty. But I guess the point is you can define whatever function you want to control the layout by returning a matrix of coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Note that there's also a function for concentric circles now in the R package `{manynet}`. (This relies on the excellent `{ggraph}` and `{Rgraphviz}` packages for plotting, but implements additional methods for most common graph-type objects.) Here is the code to replicate MrFlick's solution:

```
g <- create_filled(10) |> mutate(size = 1:10, circle = size > 5)
autographr(g, layout = "concentric", membership = "circle", 
           node_size = "size", node_color = "circle")
```

[image: coloured-concentric-manynet]

The concentric layout's "membership" argument can take various attributes or vectors, and the layout can extend to more than 2 circles/layers.